# Error CORS accediendo a servicio web desde un servicio angular

Tags: tomcat, cors

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de ionic, el motor es un **tomcat 9** que por ahora tenemos en local.

Con `npm start` podíamos probar esos servicios que comunican motor con interfaz pero ahora que estamos ejecutando la aplicación en el dispositivo, en el momento que llega a la ejecución de algún servicio nos lanza el error de CORS siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8085/recin-server/LoginServlet' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Servicio.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

private url = 'http://localhost:8085/recin-server/LoginServlet';

// Http Headers
headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset='utf-8'",
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'authkey',
});

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("Servicio login listo");
}

postLogin(login): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}`, login, { headers: this.headers });
}
}
```

Hemos intentado enviar en la cabecera del servicio el `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Authorization': 'authkey',` sin éxito.

He leído que se puede modificar el servidor para que permita diferentes url, pero no sé qué tengo que añadir ni dónde.

Comment: El problema está en el destino (tomcat), no en el origen (web ionic). Debes configurar la aplicación que corre en el servidor tomcat para que proporcione las cabeceras adecuadas. Si compartes el código java o nos dices si usas algún marco de trabajo MVC podremos guiarte en la configuración.

Comment: Aquí tienes la documentación oficial de Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ y aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo si usas Jersey para exportar un API JAX-RS: https://gist.github.com/yunspace/36b0546245c5348a34ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siguiendo la respuesta de [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia), he leído un poco la [documentación de tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter/Initialisation_parameters).

He añadido en el archivo `web.xml` del servidor Tomcat lo siguiente:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8100</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Y ya no recibo ese error.

Comment: Te llevas mi +1. Puedes seleccionar tu propia respuesta como la correcta pulsando en el icono **✔** que hay a la izquierda de tu respuesta.